# How do I properly configure cpu power settings to not overheat?

Tags: ubuntu, thinkpad, cpu-frequency, temperature, fan

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 on a Thinkpad T14s. When I push the CPUs hard, i.e. with `stress-ng --cpu 8 --tz -t 60`, I watch the core temps spike to 90°C before I panic and stop the stress test. The fan will start eventually, but not nearly soon enough, and from experiments with lesser stress levels it doesn't seem that the fan will be able to dump enough heat anyway.

I have had some good luck using thinkfan to make the fan more responsive, and that buys me some nice wiggle room at medium-high temps, but it doesn't make enough of a difference at those high spikes.

I also installed cpupower-gui. It shows me that my system is already running in the powersave mode, with a max CPU speed of 4900 MHz. If I bring down the CPUs to around 3400 MHz, the system seems to stabilize quite nicely at about 70°-75° at full load with or without thinkfan. (It's a little warmer without thinkfan.)

So, I've got a solution, but I'm unhappy with it; it seems that just permanently capping my CPUs isn't supposed to be the right answer. It is my very limited understanding that the intel_pstate driver is supposed to be implementing thermal control. I don't know how to verify if it is doing its job or not; from a functional practical perspective, it doesn't seem to be.

My questions: is there a better solution than pegging the CPU speed as I've done? And am I better off running with more aggressive fans via thinkfan, or should I drop the CPU power further and stick with the built-in auto fan curve?

Comment: What exactly CPU is it?

Comment: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10610U

Comment: Are you experiencing issues (throttling or shutdown), or is the reported temperature just getting higher than you would like?

Comment: Higher than I'd like, but I've been watching it carefully to make sure it doesn't hit the shutdown point. I'm surprised that it isn't throttling automatically more than it is -- it just seems headed for shutdown if I let it go. I assume I shouldn't let the thing fly over 100 degrees just to see what happens --- should I?

Comment: Your CPU should shut down before damaging itself.  (Source: [FAQ About Temperature for Intel® Processors](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005597/processors.html))  So I wouldn't worry too much about testing to see what happens.

Comment: @satwell, thanks for this link. That was useful and I learned a lot about how Turbo mode works.

Answer (score 1):

The TJUNCTION temperature for [your CPU](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/201896/intel-core-i7-10610u-processor-8m-cache-up-to-4-90-ghz.html) is 100°C which means Intel deems any temperature below it as safe.

Probably you haven't used laptops before or haven't paid enough attention to your temps in the past but laptop CPUs easily reach temperatures around and above 90C and it's perfectly OK for them.

Also your system won't shut down even if the CPU reaches this temperature. Intel has made their CPUs smart enough to first throttle before damaging themselves.

Comment: Thanks, Artem. It's interesting the different perspectives that are appearing here, and how it's challenging to reconcile them.

Answer (score 0):

You could just disable "turbo-boost" in BIOS, and forget about capping anything.

As to your question about the CPU scaling drivers, that doesn't matter, because when you are stressing the CPU with load, it will always go up to its highest frequency regardless of which scaling driver is employed.

Personally, I prefer the acpi-cpufreq driver with the conservative governor, so I just blacklist the intel_pstate driver at kernel boot with the `intel_pstate=disable` parameter. But again, that's not really relevant to your CPU-stressing question.

So, run your CPU stress tests again when the turbo-boost has been disabled, and let us know how it goes.

#### EDIT:

For your particular CPU, you may see two separate settings in BIOS called "Turbo Boost" and "Thermal Velocity Boost". Disable both. (Note: I've done exactly that on my laptop, and I am happy with the performance/temperature)

Comment: Turbo Boost gives you a huge uplift of performance, so that's far from advisable. For instance this CPU base frequency is 1.80 GHz, so disabling TB (4.9GHz) would mean losing almost 64% (!!) of performance.

Comment: Really? Far from advisible? It's for the OP to decide what they are using their computer for. When I disabled my tutbo-boost, I still have power 10 times over what I would ever want. Then again, one could go mental and even overclock their CPU just for sport I guess. POWER!! There's all kinds. :-)

Comment: Thanks, @Pourko. I couldn't find a turbo boost setting in the BIOS, but I was able to do it with this command: `echo  1 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo`. It worked fabulously and made the laptop run really cool; fan never kicked in and it never went over 55C;. Thaat's probably cooler than I need, even. But given that it runs so cool with this approach, I wonder if I'm better off leaving it on and just limiting the high end. Do I need to be futzing with this at all? I don't know whether or not I have faith that the CPU and OS are getting this right.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to install thermald https://github.com/intel/thermal_daemon - I maintain this for Debian and Ubuntu and it may help with overheating issues.  One can edit the default thermald profile to set specific trip values for different thermal zones, but the default profile is normally good enough.

Comment: Thanks, @ColinKing. I'm running Ubuntu, and I just checked status: apparently thermald is already running. How can I tell if it's doing what it should be doing? Just let things fly, and see if my laptop overheats and shuts down? :) Or is there a better way?